# How to set HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError and HeapDumpPath in startup.bat file on Windows XP

Tags: windows, memory, tomcat, jvm, startup

Where are the **HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError** and **HeapDumpPath** params set in the startup.bat file for Tomcat on a Windows PC? I put both params in the file as follows :

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms100m -Xmx192m
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath=c:\jakarta-tomcat\webapps

call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end
```

Is that the area where those params should go? I'm getting the following message when I **startup** Tomcat >
**The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

I'm not sure what part of the statement is incorrect. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to split a command into several lines, you have to escape the newlines.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms100m -Xmx192m ^
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError ^
-XX:HeapDumpPath=c:\jakarta-tomcat\webapps
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. I was unaware that something like that was required.